# Server-side testing forms laravel

Tags: php, laravel, automated-tests, laravel-8, laravel-dusk

I don't know if this can be done but I want to test through a cron job or but the laravel schedule forms from other websites, these websites are mine but independent from this project.
The purpose is to test the forms of several websites automatically to check that they work in the same way that would test a client, it is like making a bot that sends to the forms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel Dusk (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk) is what you need to look into.